# Eigenvalues of Hadamard product of two Wishart-type matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Given two independent Gaussian matrices with i.i.d. entries: $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$, where and $A_{i,j},B_{i,j}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Assume that $\max(p,q)<n.$ This implies that $AA^T$ and $BB^T$ have low rank.
What can be said about the scaling of the smallest eigenvalue of the Hadamard product of these two Wishart-type matrices, i.e. $\lambda_{\mathcal{min}}((AA^T)\circ (BB^T))$? Here, I'm interested in proving a non-trivial lower-bound on this quantity.
I wonder if the spectrum of this type of Hadamard product has been studied before in the literature. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting question. I have an even "simpler" problem, with $A=B$.

Comment: Shouldn't the following always hold
$$
\lambda_{\min}((AA^\top) \circ (BB^\top)) \ge \lambda_{\min}((AA^\top) \otimes (BB^\top)) \ge \lambda_{\min}(AA^\top) \lambda_{\min}(BB^\top),
$$
where the first inequality is because $(AA^\top) \circ (BB^\top)$ is a principal submatrix of $(AA^\top) \circ (BB^\top)$ ?